# Problems modify files with sed

Tags: bash, shell, sed, grep

I have a problem with the following code, if I make the 1.log file but does not modify the files containing PHP eval (..). shows me the following: `sed: no input files.`

In that I'm wrong?

```
grep -lr --include=*.php "eval(base64_decode" ./ >> 1.log | xargs sed -i.bak 's/<?php eval(base64_decode[^;]*;/<?php\n/g'
```

Comment: You're redirecting the output of `grep` to a file, so nothing is being piped to `xargs`.

Comment: And it could save the output to a log and you only keep the file path, Greetings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to save the output in the log file and also pipe it to `xargs`, use `tee`:

```
grep -lr --include=*.php "eval(base64_decode" ./ |
    tee -a 1.log |
    xargs sed -i.bak 's/<?php eval(base64_decode[^;]*;/<?php\n/g'
```

The `-a` option makes `tee` append to the file.

Comment: Thanks Barman but I see this :( 
`The command 'tee' is available in '/ usr / bin / tee "
tee: command not found 
The command 'xargs' is available in '/ usr / bin / xargs' 
xargs: command not found`

Comment: I've never seen that error message before. You should have `/usr/bin` in your `$PATH`.

Comment: I only put the backslashes because I split the command across multiple lines. If you put them on a single line, remove that.

Comment: Thank you very much man, this is what you wanted, you're a capo!

Answer (score 1):

You get the error message because your grep command does not produce any output (which you pass to sed via xargs). You probably wanted this:

```
grep -lr --include=*.php "eval(base64_decode" ./ | xargs sed -i.bak 's/<?php eval(base64_decode[^;]*;/<?php\n/g'
```

Alternative with a file list:

```
grep -lr --include=*.php "eval(base64_decode" ./ > files
sed -i.bak 's/<?php eval(base64_decode[^;]*;/<?php\n/g' $(cat files)
```

Comment: Well if this works, but looking for something a single command, thank you very much for your support!